# Renaming project renames .apk but does NOT rename deployed app on device

Tags: android, installation, adt

I'm simply trying to install slightly modified versions of a 'master ' application but have had zero luck.

Simply renaming the project in ADT (Eclipse) using Projects>Properties>rename seems to rename the resulting .apk but when I deploy-run on the device it always simply overwrites the previously installed application.

What am I doing wrong?

If I change the project name AND change all the project paths (Rightclick.Android Tools>Rename Application Package) I can install a 2nd version of the application, BUT the displayed application name is identical!

How do you change the actually displayed application name you see on the device?
Why do different project names alone not result in different apps on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the package name. Even if you change the name (btw you change it from the manifest, don't rename your project, it has nothing to do with it), it'll overwrite the previous app you deployed.

Comment: yes, strange and counter intuitive. Also I discovered that I need to edit the title_activity_main attribute node in my strings.xml, NOT the "app_name" which would make more sense!

Comment: What I meant to say is I discovered that I need to edit the title_activity_main attribute node in my strings.xml AS WELL AS "app_name".

Answer (score 2):

The name displayed on the device should be in your manifest, under `android:label` for your application:

```
<application
    ...
    android:label="My App Name"
    ...
</application>
```

Also, by default is in your strings.xml file under `app_name`.

Comment: I was going to give the very same answer... +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the app name if you want to by opening string xml file and change the value of string "app_name", as it is used in manifest file for displaying name of the app.

Comment: Also I discovered that I need to edit the title_activity_main attribute node in my strings.xml as well as "app_name".